# PowerBI: Concatenate Object List As Column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am working on creating a PowerBI dashboard that shows a list of projects and project members. I would like the list to have project as each row, and have a column named "Members" that would list of members in comma-deliminated text. Unfortunately, my data source has members as an array of objects and PowerBI appears to only support expanding arrays of strings.

I've tried Query Editor and also Advanced Editor, but can't seem to get the format/command right.

In JSON format, my data would come in like this:

```
[
    {
        projectName: "A",
        members: [
                    {
                        firstName: "John",
                        lastName: "Doe"
                    },
                    {
                        firstName: "Jane",
                        lastNahe: "Doe"
                    }
                ]
    }      
]
```

I want to be able to display it like this:

```
|  Project |  Members                 |
---------------------------------------
|    A     | John Doe, Jane Doe       |
```

Any ideas? Looks like a simple task but I had much more trouble with it than I should.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took you JSon file, added an extra project for proper testing, and used M-Query to get the result you are looking for:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\yourpath\ProMem.json")),
    #"Converted to Table1" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table1", "Column1", {"projectName", "members"}, {"projectName", "members"}),
#"Expanded members" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "members"),
#"Expanded members1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded members", "members", {"firstName", "lastName"}, {"firstName", "lastName"}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Expanded members1",{"firstName", "lastName"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Name"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Merged Columns", {"projectName"}, {{"Members", each Text.Combine([Name],", "), type text}})

in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]